# Do I need to do Try/ Catch block for invalid inputs or is a while loop enough?

Tags: java, exception, while-loop, try-catch

Often times when you are prompting the user for a value they may enter an invalid value. Is an exception(try/catch block) even necessary if you want to ask the user to prompt a new value or is simply a while loop good enough?

Comment: It varies depending on what input class or method you're using. Some throw exceptions, others return something that you have to check with an `if` statement. What are you using?

Comment: I am prompting the user for integer input through a scanner object

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [mre]. Showing code is a lot more helpful than describing it. Please [edit] your question to include your code, sample input and output, and any error messages. This will help us answer your question better.

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid using a try/catch for anything other than errors in the program.  In general, you want to prevent exceptions from happening in the first place so there is little need for try/catch blocks.  If the user could enter an incorrect value, you should just check it with an `if` statement (or the condition in your `while` loop), and prompt the user for a new value instead of throwing exceptions.